# Unable to use boolean valued promise as thenable construct in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, protractor

I am converting a Protractor page object library from JavaScript to Typescript. I have a static utility method that refreshes until an element is present (or the timeout limit is reached).

For some reason, I am unable to use a `boolean` valued promise as a `thenable` construct and I can't figure out why. The error message is `error TS2345: Argument of type '(value: boolean) => Promise<{}> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: boolean) => {} | IThenable<{}>) | undefined'.
  Type '(value: boolean) => Promise<{}> | undefined' is not assignable to type '(value: boolean) => {} | IThenable<{}>'.
    Type 'Promise<{}> | undefined' is not assignable to type '{} | IThenable<{}>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{} | IThenable<{}>'.`

The source code is below with comment showing where the compile error occurs.

I have used this sort of mechanism in the pure JavaScript version of the framework I'm converting to Typescript. What do I need to do to translate this method over to Typescript that will compile?

```
import {browser, element, ElementFinder, ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor';
import * as wd from 'selenium-webdriver';
import {By} from "selenium-webdriver";

export class ExtendedExpectedConditions {

    public static refreshUntilElementIsPresent(element: ElementFinder,  numberOfSeconds: number = 30000,
        refreshInterval: number = 5000): void {
        this.refreshElement(element, numberOfSeconds, refreshInterval);
    }

    protected static refreshElement(element: ElementFinder, numberOfSeconds: number = 30000, refreshInterval:
        number = 5000) {


        //This line throws the compile error
        element.isPresent().then(value => {
            if (!value) {
                if (numberOfSeconds <= 0) {
                    return new wd.promise.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        reject('Element cannot be found after expected retry numbers');
                    })
                }
                browser.sleep(refreshInterval).then(() => {
                    browser.refresh().then(() => this.refreshUntilElementIsPresent(element, numberOfSeconds -
                    (refreshInterval / 1000)));
                });
            }
       });
    }
}
```

My 'package.json' is below:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A test suite",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "pretest": "npm run tsc",
    "test": "node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor tmp/conf.js",
    "start_selenium": "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "update_selenium": "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "author": aperson@someplace.com,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.52",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.31",
    "any-promise": "^1.3.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.1",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json is below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "tmp",
    "types": ["jasmine", "node"],
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My conf.ts file is below:

```
import {Config, browser, protractor} from "protractor";

let testsTimeout = 3600000;
let delayBrowserTimeInSeconds = 0;

export let config: Config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    rootElement: 'body',
    seleniumServerJar:'../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar',
    chromeDriver: '../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.30',
    specs: ['tests/*Spec.js'],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        trustAllSSLCertificates: true,
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--no-sandbox']
        },
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://www.someurl.com',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: testsTimeout,
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true
    },

    onPrepare: () => {

        let origFn = browser.driver.controlFlow().execute;

        browser.driver.controlFlow().execute = function () {
            let args = arguments;

            origFn.call(browser.driver.controlFlow(), function () {
                return protractor.promise.delayed(delayBrowserTimeInSeconds * 100);
            });

            return origFn.apply(browser.driver.controlFlow(), args);
        };

        setTimeout(() => {
            browser.driver.executeScript<[number, number]>(() => {
                return [
                    window.screen.availWidth,
                    window.screen.availHeight
            ];
            }).then((result: [number, number]) => {
                browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(result[0], result[1]);
                browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
            });
        });

    },

    getPageTimeout: 120000,
    allScriptsTimeout: testsTimeout
};
```

Comment: Could you also show what versions of types do you have pinned? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I added all the configuration files to the question.

Comment: Thanks. What if you add `jasminewd2` types as well? Any changes?

Comment: @alecxe I added it to package.json & updated  question to reflect that. I cleaned out everything, did npm install and selenium_update. I still get that compile error trying to run the tests.

Comment: It looks to me as though `new wd.promise.Promise(...)` doesn't (so far as typescript can tell) implement the `IThenable` interface. Is there a good reason why you cannot just use an ordinary `Promise` for the result?  `return Promise.reject('Element cannot be found after expected retry numbers')` would be shorter code as well.

Comment: @Duncan Well, I am pretty much a novice at JavaScript, Protractor and Typescript, so I'm not sure exactly how to do what you're suggesting. I am willing to try anything that will just get the code to compile and run. I had the same method in a pure JavaScript library and it worked. I tried to translate over to Typescript and now I cannot invoke 'then' on the value. I'm not experienced enough with these tools to understand why and update it easily to fix it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem so far. Could you also show your import statements from your ts file?

Comment: @alexce updated the question with those details. I'm also using v6.10.3 of Node.js if that helps.

Comment: @Selena thanks. Just a quick check - what if you do `return element.isPresent().then(value => {` instead of just `element.isPresent().then(value => {`?

Comment: @alexce The return statement doesn't seem to have fixed it. I did a complete clean, reinstall and compilation just in case.

Comment: What is the return type of `wd.promise.Promise()`, Just hover on it and tell us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your real problem appears to be that the authors of the type library have a broken definition for the callback parameter of the `then` method. You mistyped the error message slightly in your question which makes it a bit harder to see what is going on.

```
src/test.ts(17,34): error TS2345: Argument of type '(value: boolean) => Promise<{}> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: boolean) => {} | IThenable<{}>) | undefined'.
  Type '(value: boolean) => Promise<{}> | undefined' is not assignable to type '(value: boolean) => {} | IThenable<{}>'.
    Type 'Promise<{}> | undefined' is not assignable to type '{} | IThenable<{}>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{} | IThenable<{}>'.
```

So the callback you provided to `.then` has a type of `(value: boolean) => Promise<{}> | undefined` That is to say it either returns a Promise or it returns `undefined`.

But `.then()` is expecting to be given `((value: boolean) => {} | IThenable<{}>) | undefined`
(this is where you lost a close ')' in the question) which is to say either a function or no callback. As you gave it a function we can ignore the `undefined`, so we have to give it a function that returns something or a `IThenable<something>`. The authors of this code have decided that a callback in `then` isn't allowed to return `undefined`.

So the short term fix is simple: change your `.then` callback so it always returns a result.

The longer term fix would be to report an issue to the authors of the typescript bindings for Selenium Webdriver and ask them to allow the callback to return `{} | IThenable<{}> | undefined`.

You should find this code compiles for you:

```
export class ExtendedExpectedConditions {

    public static refreshUntilElementIsPresent(element: ElementFinder,  numberOfSeconds: number = 30000,
        refreshInterval: number = 5000): void {
        this.refreshElement(element, numberOfSeconds, refreshInterval);
    }

    protected static refreshElement(element: ElementFinder, numberOfSeconds: number = 30000, refreshInterval:
        number = 5000) {


        //This line throws the compile error
        element.isPresent().then(value => {
            if (!value) {
                if (numberOfSeconds <= 0) {
                    return wd.promise.rejected('Element cannot be found after expected retry numbers');
                }
                browser.sleep(refreshInterval).then(() => {
                    browser.refresh().then(() => this.refreshUntilElementIsPresent(element, numberOfSeconds -
                    (refreshInterval / 1000)));
                });
            }
            return 42; // webdriver `.then` callback must return a result.
       });
    }
}
```

Also, for some reason the type definitions for the webdriver Promise don't declare the `.resolve()` and `.reject()` methods that the object itself does include, but you can use the `promise.rejected()` function as a simpler way to create an immediately rejected promise.

Comment: I opened a ticket against that library: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/17358

Comment: Also, thank you for the effort you put into this. I am so new to this toolchain that I'm not sure I'd have been able to pinpoint the problem on my own.

Answer (score 0):

There error you get is correct, if you look at the specs you will see that Protractor `@returns {Promise<boolean>}`, see specs [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/d726864bab2a355019832c5aaebc94e4e9ac7271/lib/element.ts#L444)

Have you ever heard of the `async / await` methods in TypeScript. It will make you live easier and your code cleaner. Your code would look like below. This should also take away your typings error.

```js
public static refreshUntilElementIsPresent(element: ElementFinder, numberOfSeconds: number = 30000,
  refreshInterval: number = 5000): void {
  return this.refreshElement(element, numberOfSeconds, refreshInterval);
}

// Add async here
protected static async refreshElement(element: ElementFinder, numberOfSeconds: number = 30000, refreshInterval: number = 5000) {

  // Wait untill the promise is resolved
  const isPresent = await element.isPresent();
  // Use the resolved promise
  if (!isPresent) {
    if (numberOfSeconds <= 0) {
      // You can clean the Promise rejection and create 1 line of code
      return Promise.reject('Element cannot be found after expected retry numbers');
    }
    // Wait for the rest
    await browser.sleep(refreshInterval);
    await browser.refresh();
    return this.refreshUntilElementIsPresent(element, numberOfSeconds - (refreshInterval / 1000));
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm still confused why I cannot invoke 'then' on the construct in Typescript when I can in pure Javascript. The nature of my question is why I can't do that. I can do that with other methods which return promises.